# What to show grandparents in Stockholm/Anytown?

Tags: sightseeing, stockholm, sweden

Yay, my grandparents have finally decided to visit me. I live in Stockholm, so I've never thought at length about what there actually is to see here. Additionally, I'm limited by walking distance constraints; my grand pa-pa isn't exactly a spring chicken.

So I'm desperate for suggestions on both what to do, what to see and how to accomplish this task without burning them out. I guess I have to form this as a plausible question - well, how about - given all the givens, what would be the best 1-day route through Stockholm, with subway/boat shortcuts and feeding frenzies?

Let's say my budget is that of a guy straight out of university, who decided not to get a job but to start his own business instead. So not way north of 100-150€.

**EDIT FIRST DAY IN**

Thanks a lot for your wonderful answers. We ended up going with what *VMAtm* suggested, and took subway to *Gamla Stan*. There were plenty of elevators, but they found Gamla Stan terrain hilly to navigate. We had to take a short break by the apparently famous ice-cream house. They complained somewhat about the ice-cream, but then we were good to go all the way to city-center metro by Åhlens.

[image: Stockholm map]

Then we took the subway to Stadion, where I used to work, and had a nice meal at whatever-that-place-is-called. They were impressed by "Köttfärslimpa" and not so much by "Lövtunn bit".

[image: Stadion map]

**THE END**

It dawned on me that I haven't updated this page. Frankly by now it's just a blur. My grand dad has now passed away, but he mentioned the trip fondly very often while he was still alive, so I must have done something right.

Comment: In case you don't already know, Stockholm is one of the most beautiful cities in Europe up there with Paris and Budapest in my opinion. That alone should please your grandparents.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't know anything about your opinion of Stockholm. ;)

Comment: Hehe I forgot you did say you'd been there for a while but I guess for future readers of this question they might still be pleased to learn of its beauty (-:

Comment: how'd the rest of the sightseeing go?

Comment: @hippietrail You forgot to add Bern to your list of beautiful cities

Comment: @Simon: Bern was nice but it didn't blow me away like the other three cities. I also didn't explore it as thoroughly.

Comment: @hippietrail I'll have to put Stockhom & Budapest on my must see list then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was there 2 years ago as a tourist. [Vasa museum](http://www.vasamuseet.se/) is totally unique - definitely worthwhile, and you can get the hop-on-hop-off bus out there, saving the walk.  The Nobel Museum is small but very worthwhile, and while you're around Ridderholmen and the palace area, you can check out the changing of the guards, and the cool little streets around that area - I really liked that.

Answer (score 6):

[Vasa Museet](http://www.vasamuseet.se/) is the bare minimum.

I am not a fan of modern art, but Stockholm is full of great examples. Some people claim that the [subway](http://www.visitstockholm.com/en/to-do/attractions/art-in-the-subway/1158) is the world's longest art exhibit. I appreciated [Millesgården](http://www.millesgarden.se/?languageID=5), including the [tourist train](http://www.avtryckt.se/lb/english.html) to go there.

If you want to see the swedish interpretation of Versailles, [Drottningholms slott](http://www.kungahuset.se/royalcourt/royalpalaces/drottningholmpalace.html) outside Stockholm is worth a try.

Don't forget everything Nobel related: [Nobel museum](http://www.nobelmuseum.se/) in Gamla Stan and the [City Hall](http://international.stockholm.se/cityhall), where the banquet takes place. If your grand parents feel good, let them climb the tower for the panoramic view over the town.

Answer (score 5):

This is higly depends on how long your grands can walk over the streets.
If you are limited with one day, I think you should start with [Gamla Stan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamla_stan):
[image]

It is the center of Stockholm, beautiful at summer, and has many cafeterias and restaurants in it. Your grands will be amazed, I think. Also you can buy [the bus tour for them](http://www.partner.viator.com/en/2268/tours/Stockholm/Stockholm-City-Hop-on-Hop-off-Tour/d907-3904BUS#pricing), or [water Hop-on-Hop-Off tour](http://www.partner.viator.com/en/1422/tours/Stockholm/Stockholm-City-Hop-on-Hop-off-Boat-Tour/d907-3904BOA).

You can [even mix it](http://www.city-discovery.com/stockholm/tour.php?id=3994), if you have that much amount of money.

Comment: +1 for Gamla Stan. Locals are bored out of their minds with it but visiting grandparents totally love it. Take care that it's not overly crowded though, some grandparents won't be comfortable in large crowds.

Answer (score 5):

Stockholm? [Skansen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skansen), [Vasa museum](http://vasamuseet.se/en/) and the historic inner city comes to mind. Was there in 2006 and there is a lot more to explore. As far as i remember there is also a castle near Skansen which was closed when i was there, and a Aquarium near Vasa museum, which was not that impressive.